# Is there an alternative for Python's eval when trying to retrieve nested attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, eval, metaprogramming

I am given a config, with one part containing multiple paths and expressions to attributes of a class. I have to retrieve the required attributes given the paths as strings in Python 3. As an example, a config may look like this:

```
...
class_foo:
   attr_x: foo.class_bar.attr_x
   attr_y: foo.dict_x['xy'].toList()
   attr_z: foo.list_x[0]
...
```

These paths could be more or less complex expressions to retrieve any attribute in nested classes. I am currently evaluating them using the eval() statement. To reduce security risk, I tried to cut the `foo.` from the input string and add it separately again, such that most other unwanted statements in a different format would fail.

```
def get_attr(foo, statement):
   return eval('foo.' + statement)
```

I am quite sure that this is not enough to prevent possible security risks, but I have not found any alternative which is not way to complex. I already tried using the `reduce` function in combination with `getattr`, but this then fails when a `dict`or `list`has to be evaluated.

Is this usecase a valid reason to use `eval()`? Is there any alternative I am missing? What can be done to make the use of `eval()` here more safe?

Comment: Can you give a full running example of the class, and what attributes exactly do you need to access?

Comment: There are different classes with quite different structures of attributes. My module imports the given classes and has to retrieve some of the attributes. The imported classes may be changed in the future and ops just want to specify the current path to the attribute in the config. The path could be anything and include any data structure, even dataframes etc.